# Non-Admin user shown in UAC prompt

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, uac

The following code checks for an admin user:

```
Text = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator).ToString();
Process p = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        Verb = "runas",
        FileName = "notepad",
    }
};
p.Start();
```

When executed by my ***non***-admin user, the first part shows "false" as expected. But in the UAC prompt - one of the "administrators" is my own account. How can that be?

(This only happens with one non-admin account. Not others on this computer. And is not offered as an option to them when executed from other accounts - they only see the real admins.)

Using a Windows 7 (x64) PC that is not connected to any other computer or domain (besides a wireless connection to the router). This was not the case until recently. Might it be that during installation of VS 2013 + Team Foundation Server somehow the account got partial Admin rights? Do *partial* admin rights even exist? (And yes. I've rebooted.)

Comment: Can you show the screen you are talking about? Isn't it 'just' the current user that is shown?

Comment: @PatrickHofman No. It is all administrators + me.

Comment: Even if your account is an administrative one, unless you started the initial process "elevated", the process still won't have administrative rights and will still generate a UAC dialog.

Comment: @martin_costello My account is _not_ an admin. That's the problem - why is it showing me my user account as an admin.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It's a real UAC prompt on Windows 7.

Comment: Are you on a domain and perhaps you are seeing the local machine's version of "ispiro" (which could be a local administrator) instead of the domain "ispiro"?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No.I added some information at the end of the question. (Yeah. I'm grasping at straws here.)

Comment: This might happen if your account is a member of any of the groups, or possesses any of the privileges, that are [filtered by UAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx#S2).  For example, if you are in the Power Users group, or possess the "Debug programs" privilege.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks. That's a very useful piece of information. Unfortunately, I tried iterating over the `WindowsBuiltInRole` enum, and found that this user account is only `IsInRole` as **User**. Your idea, though, might explain why this doesn't always happen. (Though it _does_ seem to be consistent as to which cases it offers the user as an admin.)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at the current process token rather than the properties of the underlying user account?  By definition, the filtered token will not contain any of the filtered groups or privileges.  (Well, technically it does, but they're not active so probably won't show up via `IsInrole`.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks. So how do I check that? (I used `new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())`).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with .NET to answer that.